# SharpGL Object Transparency

Tags: c#, opengl

I'm using SharpGL library for Visual C#. I want to add transparency to objects that I'm drawing. I'm creating a sphere like this.

```
SharpGL.SceneGraph.Quadrics.Sphere sphere = new SharpGL.SceneGraph.Quadrics.Sphere();
```

Then I create a material and set its colout with alpha value. Next I set the new material to the sphere.

```
SharpGL.SceneGraph.Assets.Material material1 = new SharpGL.SceneGraph.Assets.Material();
material1.Ambient = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Red);
sphere.Material = material1;
```

Even though I changed the alpha value, the transparency of the sphere doesn't change.

Comment: Have you looked into a way to change the blending mode? I don't know SharpGL, but in vanilla OpenGL you'd be calling `glEnable(GL_BLEND)` and `glBlendFunc`. They tell the GL to mix the colors of transparent objects with the pixels they are being drawn on.